# Como faz um led piscar 1,100000 segundos com o PIC?

Tags: pic

Eu estou usando o MPLAB IDE pra simular um led piscando por 1,100000 segundos.

Mas não estou conseguindo. Sempre vai para mais ou para menos.

Gostaria que vocês pudessem me dar uma dica. Ou alguma fórmula de como calcular os nop e loop que devo colocar.

```
    LIST   P=PIC16F628A
    RADIX DEC   
    #INCLUDE <P16F628A.INC>
    __CONFIG _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT & _WDT_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _BODEN_OFF & _LVP_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF  
    ;ou __CONFIG H'3F10'

    CBLOCK  0x20    ;ENDEREÃ‡O INICIAL DA MEMÃ“RIA DE
                    ;USUÃRIO
    CONTADOR1
    CONTADOR2
    ENDC            ;FIM DO BLOCO DE MEMÃ“RIA       

    ORG 0x00        ;ENDEREÃ‡O INICIAL DE PROCESSAMENTO

    INICIO
    CLRF    PORTA       ;LIMPA O PORTA
    CLRF    PORTB       ;LIMPA O PORTB
    BSF STATUS, RP0
    CLRF TRISB
    BCF STATUS, RP0

    REPETE
    BSF PORTB, 1
    BSF PORTB, 1
    CALL ATRASO0
    BCF PORTB, 1
    CALL ATRASO2
    GOTO REPETE


    ATRASO0

    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    CALL ATRASO1
    ATRASO1     
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP

    ;   

    RETURN


    ATRASO2

    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3
    CALL ATRASO3

    ATRASO3     
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP
        NOP

    ;   

    RETURN






    ;
    RETURN              


    END











    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Faz tempo que eu não trabalho com assembly no `PIC`. Quando eu trabalhava e precisava de um `delay` eu recorria a um site que gerava o código que eu precisava. Para minha surpresa este site ainda existe. E é este aqui: [Microchip PIC Delay Code Generator](http://www.piclist.com/techref/piclist/codegen/delay.htm).

Eu coloquei a configuração abaixo:

[image: Configuração utilizada no Pic Delay Code Generator]

E o código gerado foi o seguinte:

```
; Delay = 1.1 seconds
; Clock frequency = 4 MHz

; Actual delay = 1.1 seconds = 1100000 cycles
; Error = 0 %

    cblock
    d1
    d2
    d3
    endc

Delay_1_dot_1_second
            ;1099992 cycles
    movlw   0xD5
    movwf   d1
    movlw   0x66
    movwf   d2
    movlw   0x03
    movwf   d3
Delay_1_dot_1_second_0
    decfsz  d1, f
    goto    $+2
    decfsz  d2, f
    goto    $+2
    decfsz  d3, f
    goto    Delay_1_dot_1_second_0

            ;4 cycles
    goto    $+1
    goto    $+1

            ;4 cycles (including call)
    return
```